# Why doesn't a file transfer fail when the file is deleted?

Tags: macos, cocoa, file-upload, filesystems

I need to upload files to my server. I use the `ASIHTTPRequest` to do this job. But if I just add the upload job to the `ASINetworkQueue` and immediately delete the source file, the upload job can still completes successfully.

I thought the job would fail because I deleted the file. Can somebody explain the reason it still succeeds, even though the file was deleted?

Comment: On Unix systems, a file can be deleted while it is still open, and it will continue to be readable to processes that already have it open. The data is not wiped/deallocated until all processes have closed the file.

Comment: @user57368, please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem you find when you delete a large log file while a process is still writing to it, expecting to recover some disk space.

UNIX systems tend to separate the directory entries for a file from the actual data of the file.

It's the *data* that consumes the space which is why you can have hard links in UNIX, with many directory entries pointing at the same file content.

The actual data for a file is not deleted until the last process closes it, and this is almost certainly what's causing your file transfer to continue.

Deleting the file only removes the directory entry. The data is still the because the file transfer program has it open.

Once it gets closed, the data will be removed as well.